# Sumifs with a list as one critera

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I need to write a formula (assuming it is sumifs) to sum market values for a certain account number holding any of a list of numerous tickers.

[image]

=SUMIFS($H$3:$H$7,$G$3:$G$7,G3,$I$3:$I$7,K3:K6)

I have used this formlua (referring to image above), but it is not working the way I expected it to (returns a value of $9,000, should be $10,000). I am guessing it's related to attempting to use the list of tickers as a criteria, but thought that making it an array would solve that.

Hugely appreciated to anyone who can help

Comment: `=SUM(SUMIFS($H$3:$H$7,$G$3:$G$7,G3,$I$3:$I$7,K3:K6))`?

Comment: Wow, brain really hasn't turned on yet this week lol... Many thanks

Comment: No worries, BigBen is still waking up as well ;) (although he seems clearer here). If you wanted to visualize the sums, you can use `BYROW(K3:K6,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(H3:H7,G3:G7,G3,I3:I7,x)))`.